# KIE Drools Workbench unable to resolve Maven Dependecies

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, drools, kie

I have an instance of Kie drools workbench 6.4.0.Final running on a Tomcat 7 server. I am unable to add dependencies to my projects, through the work bench UI. For example if I attempt to include the [Drools Swimming Pool Model](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.chtijbug.drools/drools-framework-swimming-pool-model/2.0.3), as is done in the [user guide](https://nheron.gitbooks.io/droolsonboarding/content/gettingStarted/data_model.html), the application is unable to load the repositories packages.

Checking my Catalina logs I see the following warnings:

```
  Nov 25, 2016 2:34:11 PM org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository resolveArtifact
WARNING: Unable to resolve artifact: org.chtijbug.drools:drools-framework-swimming-pool-model:2.0.3
```

I also noticed a few errors similar to this one:

```
SEVERE: Unable to create MavenProject from InputStream
org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.12
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:298)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:62)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:55)
    at org.kie.scanner.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:33)
    at org.drools.compiler.kproject.xml.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getPomModel(AbstractKieModule.java:436)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getJarDependencies(AbstractKieModule.java:130)
    at org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver.getClassLoader(MavenClassLoaderResolver.java:65)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieModuleKieProject.<init>(KieModuleKieProject.java:68)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:188)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:172)
    at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:136)
    at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.initDeployments(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:128)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.initDeployments(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapDeployments(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:194)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.bootstrapDeployments(AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:168)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:363)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:178)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:298)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:104)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:382)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextInitialized(Listener.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.12
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:293)
    ... 68 more

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.12 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.12 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:524)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 89 more

Nov 25, 2016 8:25:55 AM org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader parseMavenPom
SEVERE: Unable to create MavenProject from InputStream
org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.12
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:298)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:62)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:55)
    at org.kie.scanner.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:33)
    at org.drools.compiler.kproject.xml.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getPomModel(AbstractKieModule.java:436)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getJarDependencies(AbstractKieModule.java:130)
    at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:179)
    at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.initDeployments(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:128)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.initDeployments(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapDeployments(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:194)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.bootstrapDeployments(AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:168)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:363)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:178)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:298)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:104)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:382)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextInitialized(Listener.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.12
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:293)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer junit:junit:pom:4.12 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.12 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer junit:junit:pom:4.12 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.12 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 80 more
```

Maven is able to resolve the Swimming pool models in a local project when I add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.chtijbug.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-framework-swimming-pool-model</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

to its pom.xml

I have my proxy set in Tomcat's Java Options with:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy_server
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

Is there any Drools or Maven configuration that I may be missing that would prevent Maven from resolving dependencies?

**New Information**

After some experimentation I realized the workbench was able to resolve dependencies when a proxy server was not used. Seems similar to the problem being experienced [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-setup/sSXoRTrf0mE). My proxy server is already set up in my settings.xml:

```
 <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy_server</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
   </proxy>
```

And these settings work just fine for my Java Projects. As stated above I have Java Options set in Tomcat for my proxy server. Are there perhaps other workbench or Tomcat configurations that could allow for Workbench to resolve dependencies behind my proxy?

Comment: I have exactly the same error in KIE Workbench 7.6 running on Wildfly 10. Did you find a solution that worked in the end?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any Drools or Maven configuration that I may be missing that
>   would prevent Maven from resolving dependencies?

Some explanations in case any of them help you with this:

1. It's normal Maven configuration to list the needed dependencies; it's what makes this work, which you discovered:

   > Maven is able to resolve the Swimming pool models in a local project
   >   when I add the dependency:

   So add each external dependency required by the KWB project to the KWB project's pom.xml.
2. After failing to find an artifact, Maven has a timeout before it will check again.  This log message from your run states that:

   > from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
   >   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
   >   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

   You can manually expire the cache, but that depends on your other tooling.  For examples, if only Maven and running from command line, use the "-U" option; however, KWB uses embedded Maven so it's probably easiest to manually remove the maven-metadata-* files in the local repo for the respective artifact.  If using an artifact manager such as Nexus, use its UI options to expire the cache for the proxied repo.
3. I'm not sure that the Tomcat proxy settings are helping/needed, since I don't know your configuration.  However, I would test without them to ensure they aren't interfering.
4. Do you have an artifact manager such as Nexus running? If so, then configure .m2/settings.xml accordingly to make Maven use it.